# Dovecot Solr schema location on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: dovecot, solr

**Short**:

where do I put the Dovecot solr-schema.xml on Ubuntu 16.04?

**Long**:

I'm currently setting up Dovecot, Postfix and a few other plugins to interact with each other.

For FTS (Fast text search) I want to use Solr via the dovecot-solr (lucene) plugin, setting this up seems straight forward as per [Dovecot documentation](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/FTS/Solr).

However in that documentation it states that one should, "Replace Solr's existing solr/conf/schema.xml using doc/solr-schema.xml from Dovecot."

But where is that really? An Google search mentions /etc/solr/conf/ (or similar), but that doesn't exist on my machine/distro by default (and it doesn't seem to help creating it either).

As of per time for writing I'm using Solr 6.2.0.

Solr was installed like this (as per Solr documentation):

> SOLR_VER=6.2.0
>
> wget https://www.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/$SOLR_VER/solr-$SOLR_VER.tgz -P /tmp
>
> tar xzf /tmp/solr-$SOLR_VER.tgz solr-$SOLR_VER/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2
>
> ./install_solr_service.sh /tmp/solr-$SOLR_VER.tgz rm
>
> rm /tmp/solr-$SOLR_VER.tgz ./install_solr_service.sh

Which setups Solr in /opt/solr by default.

Answer (score 0):

After installation package *dovecot-solr* the file `/usr/share/dovecot/solr-schema.xml` appears.

Comment: Yes true. But it's not the file I'm trying to replace, it's the one supposedly comeing with Solr when you install Solr (like I show in 1st post). From Docevot documentation: "Replace Solr's existing solr/conf/schema.xml using doc/solr-schema.xml from Dovecot.". The Solr path doesn't exist.